# Weird loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is `continue` not executing just once?

```
var flag = true;
for (let tab of tabs) {
  if (tab.url == "about:blank") {
    if (flag === true) {
      console.log("came");
      continue;
    }
    flag = false;
  }
  tab.close();
}
```

But instead, every time the first condition `tab.url=="about:blank"` is `true`, it's like it doesn't even check the other condition; (or flag is never set to `false`).

Any idea what did I do wrong here?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. The `continue` keyword skips everything until the `}` of the `for` loop.

Comment: Where did you get this code? I think `flag` should be dependent on the element from the `tab` in current iteration

Comment: @Tushar : I wrote it , apparently poorly

Comment: You just don't want to close the first "about:blank" page, is that right?

Comment: @thefourtheye : more like *one* "about:blank" page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `continue` just once you have to set `flag = false` before the `continue`. Like this:

```
var flag = true;

for (let tab of tabs) {
  if (tab.url == "about:blank") {
    if (flag === true) {
      console.log("came");
      flag = false;
      continue;
    }
  }
  tab.close();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question `Isn't the following code supposed to continue just once?`

Comment: It does, indirectly, because the answer would be just 'no'.

Comment: @Tushar , It does. :)  . My bad. :/ (Maybe this gives an example why one needs to pair program) :)

Comment: @cipher No problem, you should now rephrase the question, in future when other users will see this post, they might think that this answer is off-topic(_even when this is helpful for you_) and doesn't answer the actual question and may downvote.